# analytics API "No Hits...Pending verification" message when admin property settings show hits

Tags: google-analytics

Several weeks ago I created a new property in Google Analytics and using direct HTTP calls started using it according to the API. It all worked well and I could see all the analytics.

Yesterday I logged in to the Analytics after a couple of weeks and found it shows noting at all. The notifications show the following error message:

```
No Hits
Property ... is not receiving hits.
Pending verification
```

The data seen in the past now does not exist at all, so even when I change the period to a couple of month there is no activity at all (even though I did see it in the past)
When I check the admin > Property Settings we can see the following:

```
Property Hit Volume
Last day: 398 hits
Last 7 Days: 596 hits
Last 30 Days: 596 hits
```

So it does seem like the property is active and receiving hits. More than this in the "Real Time" dashboard I can see activity, but it only appears there. Anywhere else shows no activity at all. I also waited for more than 24 hours since we first saw this message and there are no filter at all in the Analytics.

Any idea why it shows no activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the analytics API I use the uid parameter, as described in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid

What they did not mention in this documentation, is that it requires enabling the User-ID feature. So the solution was to access the admin console of Google Analytics for this property, select "Tracking Info" > "User-ID", and follow the instruction there. Once enabled it took about 24 hours and then we started to see all the data. Do notice that  the hits prior to enabling the feature were not integrated in the analytics, so it looks like they are gone.